# If user choose one option don't allow him to choose another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with questions where the user has to choose true or false.
That list is generated automatically. But let's say I have 3 rows like these:

[image]

The html in order to see that is:

```
          <div>
            <div>
              <h2>1. You should always let your car warm up before you drive it.</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="quiz-cols">
              <div class="true-placeholder"><a href="#" data-answer="true" class="icon-true-shape amenitie_icon"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="quiz-cols">
              <div class="false-placeholder"><a href="#" data-answer="false" class="icon-false-shape amenitie_icon"></a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <h2>2. Turning off the A/C can improve fuel efficiency.</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="quiz-cols">
              <div class="true-placeholder"><a href="#" data-answer="false" class="icon-true-shape amenitie_icon"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="quiz-cols">
              <div class="false-placeholder"><a href="#" data-answer="false" class="icon-false-shape amenitie_icon"></a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <h2>3. You should top off your gas tank.</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="quiz-cols">
              <div class="true-placeholder"><a href="#" data-answer="true" class="icon-true-shape amenitie_icon"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="quiz-cols">
              <div class="false-placeholder"><a href="#" data-answer="true" class="icon-false-shape amenitie_icon"></a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And this the logic I have so far which allows the elements to change its color and stuff like that. But I want to know what can I do in order to the app doesn't allow the user to choose more than one option per row. And if the user already choose one, he can't change his pick.

```
ArticleQuiz.prototype.quizLogic = function(){
    var THIS = this;
    $('.masthead-article-quiz').parent().css('background', '#eeeeee');
    $('.quiz-cols a').on('click', $(this), function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).data('answer') === true) {
            $(this).addClass('background-green')
            $(this).addClass('new-color');
        } else if ($(this).data('answer') === false) {
            $(this).addClass('background-red');
            $(this).addClass('new-color');
        }
    });
    return THIS;
};
```

This is NOT what I want:

[image]

As you see both of them are with colors. Only one of them should have color, if the user choose the false one but at that moment that's the proper answer, the icon should be green, if it's incorrect, then the icon should be red.

Suggestios?

Comment: Simplest: use radio buttons.  Make the graphics dependent on the radio button checked / not-checked state.  Hide the radio buttons.  Simple to do with pure HTML / CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that like this:

```
$('.quiz-cols a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // exit if choice already made: users can't change their pick
    if ($(this).parents('.quiz-cols').parent().find('.new-color').length) return;
    // set class according to data-answer:
    $(this).addClass('background-' + ($(this).data('answer')=='true' ? 'green' : 'red'))
           .addClass('new-color');
});
```

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks bro!

Comment: @trincot - it may be worth pointing out that his markup means you *have* to use `.parent()`, which becomes brittle if any changes are made to the markup.  Would be beneficial to add a class to that top-level div so you could use `.closest('.quiz-row')` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Note that to do this purely with CSS, it's important that the label is immediately after the radio input, so that we can use the [+ sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Also, any radio inputs with the same name will ONLY ever allow one of them to be selected at a time.  In the example below, clicking "true" will cause "false" to become unselected, and clicking "false" will cause "true" to become unselected.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  /* Hide the radio inputs.  We don't want to see them - just the labels! */
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
  /* default style, background is gray */
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="radio"][value="true"]:checked + label {
  /* when a "true" radio is selected, background turns green */
  background: green;
  /* add other desired "on" styles here... */

}
input[type="radio"][value="false"]:checked + label {
  /* when a "false" radio is selected, background turns red */
  background: red;
 /* add other desired "on" styles here... */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="quiz-cols">
    <div class="true-placeholder">
      <input type="radio" name="amenitie" value="true" id="amenitie-true">
      <label for="amenitie-true" class="icon-true-shape"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="quiz-cols">
    <div class="false-placeholder">
      <input type="radio" name="amenitie" value="false" id="amenitie-false">
      <label for="amenitie-false" class="icon-false-shape"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about if the user has 4 or 6 choices? You are putting only 2 there.

Comment: Would it not be better to wrap the `input` in the `label`, negating the need for both the `for` attribute and the `+` selector?

Comment: I mean. Every `.quiz-cols` div is a column which should contain an option. You are putting only 2 there.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer - this is an example, you should be able to take it from here.  For the next "row" of buttons, you'd simply repeat this pattern and use a new radio input name for the new "pair" of buttons in the next row.